# Pad filename based on for parameter in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, string-formatting

I am making an image sequence fo a counter with ImageMagick in a batch script:

```
for /l %%g in (1,1,20) do imconvert.exe -background none -fill blue -font AVENIRLTSTD-LIGHT -pointsize 72 label:%%g output\%%g.png
```

This creates files in the output folder which are named as `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png`, etc...

Is it possible to pad the `%%g` parameter with zeros in the above command (in the `output\%%g.png` part)? The desired result is to get files with names like `001.png`, `002.png`, `003.png`, etc...

Or can this only be done in a separate command after the files are generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%g in (1,1,20) do (
    if %%g LSS 100 set name=0%%g
    if %%g LSS 10 set name=00%%g

     imconvert.exe -background none -fill blue -font AVENIRLTSTD-LIGHT -pointsize 72 label:!name! output\!name!.png
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way: Set a variable to the count, prefixed with enough zeros to guarantee the length is greater than or equal to the length you want. Then use a substring operation to keep the last N characters in the value (3 in your case).

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%g in (1,1,20) do (
  set "N=00%%g"
  imconvert.exe -background none -fill blue -font AVENIRLTSTD-LIGHT -pointsize 72 label:!N:~-3! output\!N:~-3!.png
)
```

Just like npocmaka, I included the 0 prefix for the label as well. Adjust if needed.

Comment: I understand nprocmaka's code, but I'm not sure the `:~-3` works. Could you explain that part please?

Comment: There is a simple way to prove whether it works (it does) - you could try it ;-)  Explanation added.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to say "I'm not sure *how* the `:~3` works". Thank you for your edit.